# Visual Studio 2010 Extensions - Custom Editor for when a class extends a specific type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I am attempting to create a GUI game designer as an extension to Visual Studio 2010 and am looking at using custom editors used with project and item templates to build this functionality ontop of existing XNA project types.

I have looked into custom editors and found various tutorials on how to make them for specific file types but I was hoping to have them be implemented dependant on the class type instead like with what currently happens with objects that extend from Control or UserControl where they have a designer and the option to view code.

Has anyone seen any tutorials or samples where anyone has managed to mimic this functionality for there own editors and class types?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question looking to do something similar:
http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/68191/416472.aspx

Here is a blog post that talks about building a custom designer (particularly for XNA):
http://badcorporatelogo.wordpress.com/2008/10/05/making-a-designer-of-your-own-an-imperfect-example/

And here is a project made by the same guy that lets you edit UI in XNA using VS:
http://ferpect.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Documentation

Hopefully these resources could be helpful to building an editor in VS. I'm not certain if he uses UserControls or not.

Comment: These are interesting but not quite what I needed, thanks anyway